# Выбрать первую запись в иерархическом запросе Oracle sql, удовлетворяющую условию

Tags: sql

нужна помощь с запросом в бд Oracle.
Допустим есть таблица objects у которой есть поля: id, parent и name.

```
OBJECTS (id, parent и name)

id - уникальный идентификатор объекта;
parent - родитель объекта;
name - имя объекта;
```

Иерархия объектов условно может быть бесконечной или очень большой, мне нужен первый элемент с заданным именем. Вот такой запрос работает:

```
 select id, name
      from objects
    where name = 'My_name'
     start with id =1
    connect by parent = prior id ;
```

Но у этого запроса минус в том, что сначала построится все иерархия, а уже потом применится условие по имени, но нам же нужен первый попавшийся, зачем нам вся иерархия.
Такой же запрос:

```
select id, name
          from objects
         start with id =1
        connect by parent = prior id and name = 'My_name';
```

Такой же запрос работает неверно, так как условие по connect by обрубается на первом же шаге.
Вообщем-то мой вопрос заключается в следующем, возможно как-то выполнить эту задачу без использования PL/SQL, ну и чтобы эффективность такого запроса была выше, чем построить всю иерархию.

Comment: Пробовали select top 1?

Comment: _мне нужен первый элемент с заданным именем_ - а сколько их у вас с заданным именем, и что называется   - первый?  Привидите пожалуйста пример исходных данных, и что вы хотите из них получить, т.е. желаемый результат.

Comment: первый попавшийся, условимся что мы точно знаем, что в иерархии всего один объект с заданным именем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо немного по другому сформулировать цель: выбрать в рекурсии все элементы до тех пор пока name НЕ равен "My_name". Это бы обрубило ветвь на предпоследнем элементе и не вывело бы нужную строку. Тогда переформулируем: продолжать рекурсию пока предыдущий элемент не равен "My_name". Или на языке oracle:

```
 select id, name
   from objects
  start with id =1
connect by parent = prior id and prior name != 'My_name';
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде бы это то, что я хотел.